# Is there a way to determine in a GitHub Actions workflow step if the current runner is self-hosted?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I have set up a self-hosted runner for GitHub Actions. It works fine but I have a step that uses [`setup-xcode-version`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-xcode-version) and this needs `sudo` access. So when it gets to this step the terminal running the GitHub Actions runner script prompts me for a password, which holds up the workflow until I enter it.

I've seen there are ways to make sudo passwordless but I don't actually need this step on my self-hosted runner because I control what version of Xcode is available. So for me a simpler and more secure option would be to just check the current runner is self-hosted or not and skip the step accordingly.

e.g. something that looks like this:

```
- name: Xcode
  id: setup_xcode
  if: contains(runner.labels, 'self-hosted')
  uses: maxim-lobanov/setup-xcode@v1
    with:
      xcode-version: 14.3.1
```

Unfortunately it looks like the [`runner` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#runner-context) does not include any `labels`. Is there some way I can achieve this check?

My runner is Apple Silicon whereas right now GitHub Actions macOS runners will presumably always be Intel, but that's not reliable enough. I suppose I could ensure my self-hosted runner names all contain a "self-hosted" keyword and check for that, but that's a bit of a hack. For now this is what I'm using and it seems to work but it relies on people remembering to include the right keyword in the runner name:

```
${{ !contains(runner.name, 'MyKeyword') }}
```

I also asked this [on GitHub](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/75621).

Comment: Sadly it looks like it would be quite awkward. The context doesn't include the _id_ of the runner, so you're left with getting the whole (paginated!) [list of runners](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/self-hosted-runners?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-self-hosted-runners-for-a-repository) and seeing if the name shows up.